# What should be done with answers that solicit upvotes?

Tags: discussion, answers

What should be done with answers that ask for upvotes? For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958774/492336):

> This programme will remove commented part,.....Okay ?
>
> Upvote this answer and select as Best answer so that it will helpful
> to others also

Should we flag them with something, or just leave them as is?

Comment: Awww, they're still so cute when they don't know the rulez yet.

Comment: Three years and yet not much more than 300 points is showing a serious lack of commitment. :)

Comment: lack of commitment to life or SO?

Comment: I see this a lot but not only from new users. I see it from established ones too. But it is frustrating when you get a comment from the OP that says something like "thanks, this solved my problem" and then thats it.

Comment: i agree @AntonyD'Andrea.. also frustrating  when op comments thanks this solved, and still another answer with a different approach keeps getting more upvotes, and yours dont get even a single .. in that case we can ask OP to accept answer if it has helped, to make the answer float on top

Comment: Just like you post this question for upvotes they also do that.

Comment: @Sunil, nope, that's not true. There is no reputation on meta.

Comment: @Jongware 3 years and yet not much more than 300 points shows a serious lack of commitment? What kind of a comment is this? It could be that people didn't have time for programming for a very long time let alone Stackoverflow. I have some time periods where I'm extremely active on SO and time periods where I haven't even looked once on SO for half a year.

Comment: ah, the meta effect, now both answer and question are heavily downvoted and deleted. Still waiting for our meta snapshots.

Comment: link is dead please relink or remove

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Like removing *any help is appreciated* and *thanks in advance* from questions, answers can be edited to clear out noise like that.

I've removed the vote begging, it has no place in an answer.

You don't need to flag this kind of behaviour unless it is systemic; e.g. the user does it in all their answers and have ignored past attempts to teach them not to do it (through edit summaries or comments); in this case it was an isolated incident.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution (and the obvious one :) ), but it won't change the future behavior. We'll have to remove it every time.

Comment: @sashoalm: if you see the user doing this *repeatedly* **then** flag it for moderator attention and they can have a word with the user. However, until such time, we can educate the user by editing, and explaining why in a edit summary or comment.

Comment: @sashoalm: And note that the community has already reacted by downvoting the answer; if the user keeps up that behaviour they'll soon enough hit the post ban where they can no longer post answers.

Comment: One could mention though that vote begging in a comment is okay if you don't do it excessively.

Comment: @Trilarion: I don't think it is okay. Produce quality answers, and upvotes will follow.

Comment: @Trilarion: teaching new users that said *thanks* in comments about how accepting answers works can be okay, within limits. But asking for upvotes is never needed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What I meant was that sometimes the asker says "nice solution" but never upvotes or accepts the answer. After a certain time passed why not asking: "if it solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer". This actually helps the community too, because others too want to know if the question was solved and in which manner. Especially for inexperienced askers reminding them politely of how SO works is actually a good thing. Asking directly for upvotes leaves a bad taste and I would be very careful with that. But I would never downvote someone asking for an upvote.

Comment: @Trilarion: right, then your choice of words was poor; I see vote begging as asking for upvotes, especially when unprompted. What you describe is about teaching new users how the site works, more than it is about asking for upvotes. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Low rep users want to have more rep quite strongly. So I see asking people to accept answers not only as teaching about how the site works but also partly as begging. I have some understanding for it. I would not downvote someone doing it.

Comment: @Trilarion: I didn't say I would either; but it has no place in *answers*. It has limited place in comments.

Comment: My comment to someone asking how to mark his question as solved: The way to mark things as "solved" (in the askers opinion, he might be wrong), is accepting the answer which helped him best understand (click the check-mark). If neccessary, that might be taking all the hints in comments and writing and accepting a self-answer (which depending on own contributions, should sometimes be marked community-wiki). Later, when you gained the privilige, you can thank others for valuable contributions by upvoting their answer (though please not just for effort).

Comment: I've got more of a problem with asking for upvotes, as opposed to asking to accept an answer if it helped (I'm guilty of doing the second one myself).

Comment: @Trilarion: It's possible to instruct new users about accepting answers without appearing like you're simply begging for rep. Eg, if I think I've written the best answer to a question by someone with <15 rep (i.e. they don't even have enough rep to vote), I often say __in a comment__ "If you like my answer please feel free to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. :)".

Comment: FWIW, I occasionally put comments directed to the OP on other people's answers suggesting that they accept the answer, eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404428/check-whether-an-element-is-in-list-or-not/28404619#comment45144303_28404619