# is it okay to flag for begging upvote?

Tags: discussion, flags, upvotes

1. Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916218/find-the-longest-common-starting-substring-in-a-set-of-strings/29346369#29346369) answer. It may serve the question, but he asked for up voting at last.
2. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192294/how-to-send-data-command-to-it-100-serial-port/22193326#comment33690696_22193326) comment. In the answer, upvote begged (if you cold not find it, see edit history) and the questioner gave upvote just for this begging.

What to do in these cases? is it okay to flag for begging upvote like these?

The link of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287723/answers-that-ask-for-upvotes) question is broken, so the example is not clear.

Comment: "upvote me for using goto!" is a joke, it is not begging.  Whether it is funny is debatable, you can simply edit out noise from any post.

Comment: @HansPassant See the author's [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22247648/revisions)

Comment: @Dronehinge example not found on that question.

Comment: Yes, I saw it, it is still just noise.  Just edit the post.

Comment: one more example here user comment for accept answer:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569278/error-on-parameter-c-sharp-sql

Comment: Related to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287723

Answer (score 4):

I would either comment to have the user remove it or just edit it out as it contributes nothing to the answer.  This isn't something that a moderator needs to get involved in unless this is something they are doing on every answer.

Comment: I edited my answer and added another example, please update your answer if you think it needs. sorry for this.

Comment: @manetsus Since these are different users my advice still stands.

Answer (score 4):

The author of the first answer isn't actually begging for upvotes...

He's just humorously poking fun at the "goto is the work of the devil"-crowd, which is characterized by raising rules of thumb, which have a rationale and scope of applicability, to unprecedented, doogmatic and exceptionless hights.
A real art-work of an answer on MSE about them: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354

Just leave it be, and if you are part of the mentioned crowd, reconsider your zeal.

---

As to the second, edit it out and comment to the poster. Though if it's a pattern (or he prooves stubborn), flag for a mod to handle it (concisely and thoroughly mention everything relevant, eventually after a short summary).