# OP rejected edit to remove upvote request

Tags: discussion, answers, rejected-edits

I noticed an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69752803/14104186) (since deleted by the author) that had a sentence at the bottom asking to accept and upvote if the answer was useful. I remember reading something that said omit any such sentences as it adds nothing to the answer, which is what I thought. I couldn't remember where I saw it, but I found a [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287723/answers-that-ask-for-upvotes) post where people agreed that this sort of thing should be removed.

I made an [edit request](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30200292), but it was rejected by the OP. Is there some way to contest these sorts of rejections? Or should I just leave it as is?

Comment: That is "[not even fluff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong)". It doesn't belong and even as a comment it should be removed.

Comment: Somebody beat me to it, but let others who have >2k edit it out. You can add a comment referring the user to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as indicative that users know what should be done.

Comment: While correct, such edits are risky when you have less than 2k reputation, since you can only suggest them. It's then likely the author will see them and they have a binding vote on suggested edits. Since they added it to their post to begin with, they are likely not wanting others to edit it out (same with "Thank you in advance" and other fluff), even if they are wrong and the editors correct, and then you have one more rejected suggested edit.

Comment: Even if you have >2k, it's always possible that the original author rolls back legitimate edits like this. In such cases, you should flag the post for moderator intervention. Explain that you've tried to submit an edit, but the OP rolled it back, so you need a mod to reinstate the edit and lock the post. (Only do this for edits that are *absolutely* correct, like this one. Not where there is anything subjective about it.)

Comment: This doesn't guarantee an accepted edit otherwise, but your choice of words for the edit reason might have been a bit upsetting to the poster *(the "begging")*, and an edit properly explaining the issue, or simply stating *"removing fluff"* might've been more effective.

Comment: @OlegValter I linked this question in my question, but it didn't quite solve what I was asking. The comments above have been very helpful though

Comment: I know - it is an automated comment when voting to close. The root issue  and the answer is identical: having upvote/accept/whatever soliciting in answers is unacceptable and should be edited out. If anyone authoritative (pointing finger at @CodyGray :)) is going to post an answer here specifically tailored to the situation "what is the correct course of action when the OP rolls back edits removing parts that solicit upvotes/accepts", I will be happy to retract - for now I think this can serve as a good signpost for others ( the reason why I cast a vote ).